# Order By order, parent_id and group?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I'm really not sure how to exactly phrase what I'm looking to do therefore I'm having trouble searching. I have a table of `pages` that each have an `id`, `title`, `order` and `parent_id` if the `parent_id` is `NULL` that's considered a top level page. I'm able to almost sort this correctly with `ORDER BY` by `parent_id` and `order` with the following query:

```sql
select `id`, `title`, `order`, `parent_id`
from pages
order by `order` AND COALESCE(`parent_id`, `order`), `parent_id` is not null, `order`
```

The query spits out the following:

| id | title | order | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 107fa138 | video | 0 | NULL |
| 8eeda86c | mn | 2 | NULL |
| cac640ad | xxe title | 3 | NULL |
| 1ce4d070 | sdfsdfsdf | 4 | NULL |
| b45dc24d | another | 1 | 8eeda86c |
| d3490141 | hello | 9 | 8eeda86c |

This is *almost* what I want. Ideally, I'd have the rows with `parent_id`s directly under the row with that `id` so *ideally* the sort order would look like this:

| id | title | order | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 107fa138 | video | 0 | NULL |
| 8eeda86c | mn | 2 | NULL |
| b45dc24d | another | 1 | 8eeda86c |
| d3490141 | hello | 9 | 8eeda86c |
| cac640ad | xxe title | 3 | NULL |
| 1ce4d070 | sdfsdfsdf | 4 | NULL |

I don't even know how I would go about this. If someone can point me in the right direction that would be very awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
order by `order` AND COALESCE(`parent_id`, `order`), ...
```

This probably isn't doing what you think it's doing. The `AND` is a boolean operator, so it will be as if you had written this expression:

```
order by (`order` > 0) AND (COALESCE(`parent_id`, `order`) > 0), ...
```

That is, if both `order` and the other term are nonzero, then 1, else 0.

I think the following would get closer to what you describe:

```
order by COALESCE(`parent_id`, `id`), 
    `parent_id` is not null, 
    `order`
```

---

Demo:

```
create table pages ( id varchar(10) primary key, title text, `order` int, parent_id varchar(10) );  

insert into pages (id, title, `order`, parent_id) values 
('107fa138', 'video',     0, NULL),
('8eeda86c', 'mn',        2, NULL),
('cac640ad', 'xxe title', 3, NULL),
('1ce4d070', 'sdfsdfsdf', 4, NULL),
('b45dc24d', 'another',   1, '8eeda86c'),
('d3490141', 'hello',     9, '8eeda86c');

select `id`, `title`, 
  COALESCE(parent_id, id) as cpi, 
  parent_id is not null as pinn, 
  `order`, 
  `parent_id` 
from pages 
order by COALESCE(`parent_id`, `id`), `parent_id` is not null, `order`

+----------+-----------+----------+------+-------+-----------+
| id       | title     | cpi      | pinn | order | parent_id |
+----------+-----------+----------+------+-------+-----------+
| 107fa138 | video     | 107fa138 |    0 |     0 | NULL      |
| 1ce4d070 | sdfsdfsdf | 1ce4d070 |    0 |     4 | NULL      |
| 8eeda86c | mn        | 8eeda86c |    0 |     2 | NULL      |
| b45dc24d | another   | 8eeda86c |    1 |     1 | 8eeda86c  |
| d3490141 | hello     | 8eeda86c |    1 |     9 | 8eeda86c  |
| cac640ad | xxe title | cac640ad |    0 |     3 | NULL      |
+----------+-----------+----------+------+-------+-----------+
```

By adding in the columns that show the sorting expressions we can see how the sort occurs.

First it sorts by `cpi` alphabetically. This prefers the `parent_id` if it is set, but defaults to `id`.

For ties of `cpi`, then it sorts by `pinn`. So 0 comes before 1.

For ties of `pinn` (i.e. when multiple rows have a value 1), then it sorts by `order`.

Is this not what you wanted?

Comment: I droped the `order by order` part and it seems to return the same results. I think you're right in that it wasn't doing what I expected, but it's still not returning any different ordering

Comment: I have made an edit above. Apologies, I was thinking of it but I didn't include the change in my original answer.

Comment: Hey thanks @BillKarwin for the help, that does indeed get me closer! I'm going to as one more question here because I'm just not grokking how this works. The children are indeed under the parent, this is great, but the sort order is messed up with the `null` values. I'm getting 0, 4, 2...3 where I'd expect (or hope) to get 0, 2...3, 4.

Comment: AH! Got it, thank you! That's exactly what I wanted and I wasn't fully getting it so it looked wrong, but this is a great explanation. Thank you!